# Can someone explain this JDBC Exception to me?

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc

I'm gettting the following exception when performing an insert to an Oracle Databse using JDBC.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Unexpected packet
```

What could cause this and how can I recover from it?

The application I'm writing performs an aweful lot of updates the the databse in rapid succession. Judging from the exception I'd assume it's a network issue, however the Database is on the same box as my Application.

I don't have a stack trace and this is one of those irritating "Works on my machine" problems" where it Borks when I put it on a client site.

Unfortunately I've got to throw together something that will fix this/diagnose but the client site only throws data to my app between 5pm and 9 pm when I'm out of the office...

I've got a few hours to work out my contingencies though...

Any thoughts.

**Problem solved:**

It was a synchronization issue.

Comment: Any unclosed cursors/resultssets?

Comment: There are no result sets, it's an insert only system. Another system recives the data... assuming it ever gets there... :(

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? Was it related to multithreading?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I resolved this, and it was because there were multiple threads using the same driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you per any chance using multiple threads and forgot synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a driver problem, is there an updated driver for the server version you're using?  Also, make sure you don't have older versions of the ojdbc jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

How many inserts in a batch?

Under some conditions, its advisable to have a commit-threshold in a transaction. If you're doing transactions, you should keep aware of that.

btw, any stack traces?